# Referencing "external function" in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a bunch of auto-generated SQL files which contain the PL/SQL code for Oracle stored procedures.

**The problem:** Let's say the stored procedure `sp_myproc` in file `file1.sql` contains a reference to the function `f_myfunc` in `files2.sql`. When `file1.sql` is executed before `file2.sql`, we get an error since `sp_myproc` references the not-yet-existing function `f_myfunc`.

These references can be quite complex, so we need a general way to handle this situation (we can't just reverse the order of the files).

**The solutions:**

1. The first option is to just let the scripts run twice. The first time we would get the error, but the second time they would run fine. This is how we are doing it now, but we are looking for a better option since a customer is complaining about the errors. Another flaw of this approach is that we need to run the scripts more than two times if the references get more complex.
2. Insert some kind of `IF NOT EXISTS CREATE FUNCTION f_myfunc` before the `CREATE` statement of `sp_myproc`. This would insert a dummy function `f_myfunc`, which would later be replaced by the real one. We tried this approach but it's ugly, since a `IF ... THEN CREATE FUNCTION` is illegal (DDL inside of PL/SQL), so we would need dynamic SQL.
3. The best option would be to have some kind of `DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION f_myfunc` statement which tells the compiler that `f_myfunc` will be created later if it doesn't yet exist. This is some kind of **external function reference** like those in C, C# etc., which are accepted by the compiler, and resolved later by the linker. I'm aware that PL/SQL doesn't behave like C or C#, but I'm hoping that there is a similar method here.

**Does PL/SQL have a statement like the one in option 3?**

**Are there other options?**

Comment: Short answer - Oracle doesnot have what you're looking for in option 3. Best would be to resolve the order of your functions in which they are being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your functions in packages you can reduce the problem, but it is hard to completely avoid it.

If you use packages you simply need to compile the specifications before the bodies and you will avoid the problem.

Note that there are some rare cases where you cannot use a function that is inside a package, but as long as the raw functions only use packaged functions you still avoid compilation errors caused by inter-function dependencies.

**Suggested compilation order:**

- Package Specifications
- Functions and Procedures (outside packages)
- Views
- Package bodies